# Camera image overexposed after LED flash enabling

Tags: android, camera, computer-vision

I'm doing some work with computer vision on Android. I have made an app that keeps the exposure low after calibration with exposurelock, and that works fine. The exposure is how I want it with the LED on and off for almost all video frames.

However after I toggle the LED flash from the camera on, the image is shortly overexposed.

Since the exposure is locked, this is something that I do not understand why it is happening.

I'm testing with a Moto G2nd and Nexus 5X. Only the Nexus 5X seems to show the problem. From what I've read there are some difficulties with setting exposure compensation (which the Nexus 5X lacks), but the exposurelock is sure to work, although I'm beginning to doubt it has flaws. The Moto G2nd has the exposure compensation set to minimum (which here it does work).

Begging the question; is the shortly overexposed frame the result of the Nexus drivers, missing exposure compensation, or is it a natural occuring problem?

If the latter is the case, can I counteract it? I've thought about keeping track of the overall brightness of the frame and comparing that with a not overexposed one a few frames back. This seemed tricky and not to work.

Sidenote: maybe worth to mention, is that the Nexus shortly seems to stutter the video output after setting the camera parameters (flash on or off). Would it be conceivable that during this stutter the CMOS is charged too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this some more. Nexus support wasn't of any help, so I basically had to work around the problem. I ended up timing the flash (there's a delay in case of Nexus 5x) by watching the brightness of the frame. Instead of just timing from flash low to high, I add another frame at the end to account for one overexposed frame.

I'm not sure this same issue happens when turning the flash off. I would guess so as there's a significant framedrop around powering off the flash, just as when powering on. Either way, that doesn't seem a problem for me (yet).

My guess this is a problem with the camera driver and the CMOS is indeed charged too long, because frames are not fetched in time, due to a delay by enabling/disabling the flash.